# Unable to delete multiple redis keys in nodejs using 'redis' package

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I have redis keys following a pattern like follows:

```
ZZprefixA-1
ZZprefixA-2
ZZprefixA-3
ZZprefixB-1
ZZprefixB-2
ZZprefixB-3
...
```

I want to all delete keys matching the  following pattern

```
ZZprefixA-*
```

My code looks like following:

```
const redis = require('redis')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const options = {
  host: REDIS_HOST,
  port: REDIS_PORT,
  prefix: 'ZZ'
  password: REDIS_PASSWORD,
}

if (REDIS_PASSWORD) {
  options.password = REDIS_PASSWORD
}

const redisClient = redis.createClient(options)

delAsync = promisify(redisClient.del).bind(redisClient)
getKeysAsync = promisify(redisClient.keys).bind(redisClient)
```

Now I am trying to delete keys matching the pattern in following way:

```
const keys = await getKeysAsync(`ZZprefixA-*`)

const result = await delAsync(keys)

console.log(result)

const dkeys = await getKeysAsync(
      `ZZprefixA-*`
    )
console.log(dkeys)
```

The console log of 'result' prints 0, and 'dkeys' prints the matching keys despite having called del function on the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `prefix: 'ZZ'` cause you problem, when you set key `prefixA-1`, redis will auto add prefix `ZZ` then the key become `ZZprefixA-1`. When you try del keys, redis will also add prefix `ZZ` to your geted keys `ZZprefixA-1 ZZprefixA-2 ZZprefixA-3`, then your real delete keys are `ZZZZprefixA-1 ZZZZprefixA-2 ZZZZprefixA-3`. While these keys is not exists, so nothing happens and your keys reserved.